# Loop Two Array in Single Loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I want to make a form input with dynamic Name Label and Value, 
there are two arrays, how to make it loop in single foreach ?

This is an example:

```
<?php 
$value = explode(',',$row['value']); 
$name = explode(',',$row['name']); 
for($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) { 
echo $name; 
echo $value; 
}
?>
```

$row Variable is an Array,
This method didn't work for me. Any suggestions?

Comment: what about absence of value represent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why cant you use [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) before loop, try this..

```
<?php 
$value = explode(',',$row['value']); 
$name = explode(',',$row['name']);
$combainedArray = array_combine ( $name , $value );
foreach($combainedArray as $name => $value ) { 
          echo $name, '=>', $value; 
}
?>
```

### **OR**

if you don't what to combine make it like this..

```
<?php 
$value = explode(',',$row['value']); 
$name = explode(',',$row['name']); 
$count = count($value);
for($x = 0; $x < $count; $x++) { 
   echo $name[$x]; 
   echo $value[$x]; 
}
?>
```

Comment: if using foreach, it be possible to use parameters ?
for example $combineArray['name'] and $combineArray['value']

Comment: No, here you will get $name as KEY and $value as VALUE of array and loop until getting the end of array.

Answer (score 1):

As a solution to above mentioned problem,Please try executing below mentioned code snippet.

In consideration with same no of form fields for name and value

```
<?php 
$value = explode(',',$row['value']); 
$name = explode(',',$row['name']); 
for($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) { 
echo $value[$x];
echo $name[$x];
}
?>
```